# Highlight Gridview selected row asp.net (visual studio 2012)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, gridview

How do I highlight a selected gridview row in asp.net (visual studio 2012)

Here is my .aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="LessonsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="swim_ID,Expr2,fac_ID" DataSourceID="LessonsDataSource" AllowSorting="True" Width="1050px">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="swim_ID" HeaderText="Class ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="swim_ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="swim_Start" HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="swim_Start" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="swim_Num_Classes" HeaderText="Lessons" SortExpression="swim_Num_Classes" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fac_Street" HeaderText="Street" SortExpression="fac_Street" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fac_City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="fac_City" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="lev_Name" HeaderText="Level" SortExpression="lev_Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="lev_Cost" HeaderText="Cost" SortExpression="lev_Cost" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="lev_Max_Enroll" HeaderText="Max Space" SortExpression="lev_Max_Enroll" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="lev_Min_Age" HeaderText="Min Age" SortExpression="lev_Min_Age" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="lev_Max_Age" HeaderText="Max Age" SortExpression="lev_Max_Age" />
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
```